# AngularJs - Bind to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've had a simple setup displaying a variable using ng-bind-html. But now requisites have changed and I part to display comes from a collection and needs to display a pager.
So I thought about using a functionI , thinking that it would be easy, but failing miserably at it.

The expected workflow:

1. Via AJAX I load the content of a select field (working)
2. When the user selects one of the options, the function should get called to paint the content from the collection that is assigned to the selected option, including a pager to navigate within the collection (not working).

What I have so far:

```
{% extends 'BDAMainBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Kurs-Auswahl{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <div data-ng-controller="SingleCourseDownloadCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        {{ textSnippet('snippet.solo_download_selection')|raw }}

        <div data-ng-show="loading">
          <span class="inline-ajax-indicator"></span>
        </div>

        <div data-ng-hide="loading || courses.length == 0" class="input-group">
      <select
        class="form-control"
        data-ng-change="tcAccepted = false"
        data-ng-model="course"
        data-ng-options="c|courseSelectionCourseLabel for c in courses"
      ><option value="">Bitte wählen:</option></select>

      ....

    <div data-ng-show="course">
      <div>
        {% verbatim %}
          {{ paged_weekly_exercises }}
        {% endverbatim %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ....
{% endblock %}
```

and:

```
app.controller('SingleCourseDownloadCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 'CourseManager', 'RemoteRouteConfig', function ($scope, $window, CourseManager, RemoteRouteConfig) {
  $scope.courses = [];
  $scope.loading = true;
  $scope.paged_weekly_exercise;
  $scope.course = [];

// load
CourseManager.getAvailableForSoloDownload().then(function (response) {
  $scope.courses = response;
  $scope.loading = false;

  $scope.$watch('course', function(){
    if(!course.length){
      return false;
    }
    $scope.paged_weekly_exercise = $scope.course.weekly_exercises[0].content;
  });
});

// starts the given course for single download
$scope.startCourse = function startCourse(course) {
  $window.location = RemoteRouteConfig.course.startSoloDownload({
    course: course.id
  });
 }; 
}]);
```

But I feel I went a totally wrong path. How should I go to accomplish my goal?

I have minimal experience with Angular, but am quite decent at Javascipt and JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a watcher in your controller, just use the `ng-change`:

```
<select
    class="form-control"
    data-ng-change="courseChanged()"
    data-ng-model="course"
    data-ng-options="c|courseSelectionCourseLabel for c in courses"
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.courseChanged = function() {
    $scope.tcAccepted = false;

    var course = $scope.course; // the used ng-model
    if(!course.length){
        return;
    }

    $scope.paged_weekly_exercise = course.weekly_exercises[0].content;
}
```

Comment: That sounds good... will try as soon as I'm before the computer.

Comment: Note that you should take a close look to your `course` defining: On top you say `$scope.course = []` (array), then you use `course.length` (still array), then you use `course.weekly_exercises..` (not array?)

Comment: Yep, that were just for testing and I'll get rid of it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a  lot.